# Table expiration is NEVER in bigquery but the date is available for 60 days

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics

We have billing account and I have changed Table expiration from 60 days to never last month. I have already checked GA4 and firebase and they also show no expiration date. However the data is available for the last 60 days in the tables in bigquery. Do I need to adjust something else in Google cloud or somewhere else to keep the data for longer time? I need the data at least for 1 year.

I have also searched in internet for the same issue but couldn't find any relevant answer.

Comment: Checking the dataset level settings might be helpful. Make sure that the default table expiration time at the dataset level is not set to a shorter duration than desired.

Comment: @AkshatGoel Thanks for your reply and hint! Do you mean to check the dataset per date/day or dataset level means something else?  I see now that the dataset of some days has expiration time of 60 days.

Comment: @Mina I have the same issue, By chance did you find the solution?

Comment: @JohnOwen, as Rob mentioned below it is important to also adjust the available subtable of these 60 days. Then the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at each individual events_ subtable (?) you can edit the details and see that it has an expiration date set, from before when the setting was changed. I think you have to go through each dated table and fix it manually.

Comment: Thanks Rob! This was indeed the solution.